# document.getSelection().anchorOffset is always zero. nodeType issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code I am looking at has been done using React and is meant to store the full text of an input field, the selected text within that field, and the index of the selected text within the full text.

```
<Form.Control
 id='left'
 type='text'
 placeholder='LHS'
 onSelect={element => logSelection(element)}
/>

function logSelection(element) {

  var fullText = element.target.value;
  var selectedText = document.getSelection();
  var selectionPosition = document.getSelection().anchorOffset;
```

fullText and selectedText store the desired values, selectionPosition always stores zero. I think it has to do with the type of anchorNode being used. nodeType gives a 1, whereas I think I need type 3, a text node. How can I get the correct value stored to selectionPosition?